# Best way to programmatically return widget wrapped by a parent widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I wan't to disable iOS dynamic type completely for my Flutter app as it completely destroys some of my layouts when the user sets the global text size too high.

I asked the question on how to accomplish this [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25587) and got this answer that I would like to implement.

```
return MediaQuery(
  child: your-widget-here,
  data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
);
```

Just curious about the best way to implement that using DRY principles so that I can re-use it throughout my code. At the moment, I have simply created a Utils class written a method like so

```
Widget unscaledWidget(Widget widget, BuildContext context){
  return MediaQuery(
    child: widget,
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
  );
}
```

and then in the build methods of the pages in my app instead of calling

```
return Scaffold(...);
```

doing

```
Scaffold scaf = Scaffold(...);
return Utils().unscaledWidget(scaf, context);
```

Is there a better way I should be accomplishing this? Just not sure this is Dart best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason that your method needs to be a member of a class. If you make it a top level function (outside of a class) you save several characters (and the unnecessary construction of a `Utils` - though this could equally be achieved by making it a `static`).

Outside a class, declare this:

```
Widget unscaledWidget(Widget widget, BuildContext context) => MediaQuery(
      child: widget,
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
    );
```

and use it like this

```
  return unscaledWidget(Scaffold(...), context);
```

Comment: That's fine if I want to use it in one class, but if I have a dozen different scaffolds spread across a dozen different files (all of which I want to apply the textScaleFactor to) that would not be possible.

Comment: Why wouldn't you then use the same `unscaledWidget(` bit in front of every scaffold?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realise that it was even possible to define a method outside of a class like that. Just gave it a try and it worked well.